# Why does ArcPy Excel To Table give AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute?

Tags: python, arcpy, excel

I'm trying to import an excel workbook using arcpy. ExcelToTable, but I get the following traceback:

ERROR

```
updateParameters Execution Error: Runtime error Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Conversion 
Tools.tbx#ExcelToTable_conversion.UpdateParameters.py", line 4, in File 
"c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.2\ArcToolbox\Toolboxes\Conversion Tools.tbx
#ExcelToTable_conversion.UpdateParameters.py", 
line 40, in updateParameters AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 
'get_sheet_names'
```

I have imported arcpy, have I missed something else?

EDIT: Here's my code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\Users\\Ant\\Documents\\ArcGIS\\ITN.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = True

x = 1
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("Sites",["SizeScore","SizeWt","UPRNScore","UPRNWt"]) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    SQL = "FID = {0}".format(x)
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("Sites","Siteslyr",SQL)
    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("Siteslyr","C:\\Sites.xls")
    def RunExcelMacro(name):
        myExcel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        myExcel.Visible = 0
        myExcel.Workbooks.Add('c:\\Data\\UpdateScores.xlsm')
        myExcel.Run(name)
        myExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0
        myExcel.Quit()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        RunExcelMacro('MacroEnableDBF')        
    def RunExcelMacro(name):
        myExcel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
        myExcel.Visible = 0
        myExcel.Workbooks.Add('c:\\Data\\UpdateScores.xlsm')
        myExcel.Run(name)
        myExcel.DisplayAlerts = 0
        myExcel.Quit()       
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        RunExcelMacro('AppendScores2')
    arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("C:\\Sitescores.xls", "Carescores")
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Carescores", fields) as curs:
        for rows in curs:
            row[0] = rows[0]
            row[1] = rows[1]
            row[2] = rows[2]
            row[3] = rows[3]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
    x = x + 1
```

Comment: You need to post your code as well, not just the error message.

Comment: Are you able to cut down your provided code to a snippet that still shows the error?  If so, that will make it easier to debug. I recommend that you use the edit button to revise your question to incorporate in a readable way the learnings from advice offered so far.

Comment: now edited to a reduced version that still creates the error

Answer (score 3):

Two things I noticed are:

1. The line with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor... has no opening square bracket "[" but it has a closing "]"
2. The line arcpy.ExcelToTable_conversion("C:\Sitescores.xlsx", "Carescores") has just one \ when it should be two.

Comment: added another backslash but same attribute error

Comment: Ok, on your add workbook lines you have a file extension xlsm, is that valid? I am not familiar with that.

Comment: yep, that's the workbook with the macros that i am running, xlsm is macro-enabled workbook

Answer (score 1):

The alternative is to create a csv rather than xls and then use arcpy.TableToTable_conversion, which did the trick. Doesn't explain the error above though.

Comment: The very first line of the help file for this tool says "Excel To Table supports Excel Workbooks (.xlsx) and Microsoft Excel 5.0/95 Workbook (.xls) formats as input". It does not say it supports xlsm...

Comment: the input for the tool is C:\Sitescores.xlsx, not the xlsm file

Comment: OK, I'll keep plugging away. Why do you have an update cursor you don't appear to update "sites". Also x never increments so SQL is always the same, is that you intention?